launch puppeteer without blocking the cli
using puppeteer, i wrote a code that will be executed from the command line and i want to open the browser, navigate to a web page, keep the browser open and retain control to the command line.
// index.js
(async() => { 
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("https://stackoverflow.com");
})();

but while the browser is open, the command line never gains back the control (browser.close() must be called, but this is not what i want). how can i make the code not to block the command line? (i do not want to execute the code background from the command line (appending & to the execution command))

Why don't you want to append & to the command? That's the answer. Puppeteer can't run without the Node parent process being alive. Kill the process, Puppeteer is gone. & backgrounds the process so you can continue working on the command line while Node runs. What are you trying to accomplish? Can you provide more context for your use case--what commands are you needing to run while Puppeteer is active?

would like to save time by not have to launch the browser each time i iterate on my development. for instance, running the code above multiple times without closing the browser.

Ah, then you probably want to open the browser once and connect to it from your script. When the script ends, the browser won't close (if you don't call browser.close()). You can then run the script again (or run another script) and keep connecting to the same persistent browser. You might want to edit your post to be a bit clearer about your use case.

thanks! :) can you include an answer that demonstrates how to launch the browser while returning control to the cli and while executing again, finding the browserWSEndpoint and connect to the browser?

Just to clarify, when you "return control to the cli", you're OK with exiting the Node process, right? If so, then use browser.disconnect() rather than browser.close() in your script. See this answer from the other thread. I think it should completely solve your problem.

would appreciate a concrete example for lunching, disconnecting and connecting.

Which part of that is missing from this answer? Do you want to start the browser with Puppeteer rather than running Chromium on the command line?

yes, i would like to start the browser with puppeteer.

Got it, I'll post an answer momentarily.

@ggorlen will be waiting for it. thank you :)

Based on the comments, it sounds like you want to launch your browser with Puppeteer, then disconnect and exit the Node process without closing the browser, and then be able to reconnect to the same browser with another script (or the next time you run the same script).
This isn't yet supported, so the easiest workarounds at the moment are either to launch the browser yourself (example), or keep a Node process open to babysit the browser it's launched using the standard puppeteer.launch() call (don't call .close() to keep the process open indefinitely).
The problem with doing it all from Node, without the extra babysitter process, is that when the Node process spawns the browser process with puppeteer.launch(), the child browser process is not detached, so killing the parent process also kills the child. According to this currently open issue, there's no puppeteer.launch() option to detach the browser child process at the moment. You can subscribe to that issue in case an option is added down the line.
Until that's supported, here's a somewhat hacky workaround tested on Ubuntu 22.04 with Chromium Version 125.0.6422.141 (Official Build) snap (64-bit), Node 22.11.1 and Puppeteer ^22.10.0, using Node's spawn to launch the browser and detach the child.
const {setTimeout} = require("node:timers/promises");
const {spawn} = require("node:child_process");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const reconnectOrLaunch = async (
  browserURL = "http://localhost:9222"
) => {
  try {
    return await puppeteer.connect({browserURL});
  } catch (err) {
    // ignore and try launching a child process below
  }

  // Hack: launch browser manually since browser.launch()
  // doesn't yet support a 'detach' option
  const childProcess = spawn(
    "chromium",
    [`--remote-debugging-port=${browserURL.split(":").pop()}`],
    {
      detached: true,
      stdio: "ignore",
    }
  );
  childProcess.unref();

  // Hack: poll up to ~30s until browser connection succeeds
  for (let tries = 300; tries > 0; tries--) {
    await setTimeout(100);

    try {
      return await puppeteer.connect({browserURL});
    } catch (err) {
      // ignore; we'll throw later if we run out of retries
    }
  }

  throw Error("Unable to connect to browser");
};

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await reconnectOrLaunch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.goto("https://www.example.com", {
    waitUntil: "domcontentloaded",
  });
  console.log(await page.$eval("h1", el => el.textContent));
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.disconnect());

Since the browser isn't ready right away, I'm polling until it's ready. There's certainly room for improvement, but this should get you started.
